# How to fill missing values in categorical data based on other columns?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have following data frame with missing values:

```
type  price product
-------------------
food  19.0  apple
food  12.0  egg
food  21.0  NaN     <-- missing
drink 21.0  wine
drink 10.5  soda
drink 12.0  NaN     <-- missing
```

I want to fill the missing `product` values based on closest `price` in its `type`, so it will become:

```
type  price product
-------------------
food  19.0  apple
food  12.0  egg
food  21.0  apple   <-- filled
drink 21.0  wine
drink 10.5  soda
drink 12.0  soda    <-- filled
```

Is there a simple way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
tmp = df.reset_index().sort_values(by='price')
m = df['product'].isna()

s = (pd.merge_asof(tmp.loc[m, ['type', 'index', 'price']],
                   tmp.loc[~m, ['type', 'price', 'product']],
                   on='price', by='type', direction='nearest')
       .set_index('index')['product']
    )

df.loc[s.index, 'product'] = s
```

Output:

```
    type  price product
0   food   19.0   apple
1   food   12.0     egg
2   food   21.0   apple
3  drink   21.0    wine
4  drink   10.5    soda
5  drink   12.0    soda
```

Comment: Great answer, never used `merge_asof()` before. It seems s can be simplified as: `s = pd.merge_asof(tmp.loc[m], tmp.loc[~m], on='price', by='type', direction='nearest').set_index('index_x').product_y`

Comment: @ubertao yes, you can do this. I personally try to avoid using the `_x`/`_y` values of a merge, but it's a personal taste ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy broadcasting for get minimal indices of difference of non missing with missing prices with absolute values with [`numpy.argmin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html), last replace `NaN`s by set values by array `out`:

```
def f(x):
    
    m = x['product'].notna()
    a = x['price'].to_numpy()
    b = x['product'].to_numpy()
    
    arr = np.abs(a[m] - a[~m][:, None])

    out = b[m][np.argmin(arr, axis=1)]
    
    x.loc[~m, 'product'] = out
    return x


df = df.groupby('type').apply(f)
print (df)
    type  price product
0   food   19.0   apple
1   food   12.0     egg
2   food   21.0   apple
3  drink   21.0    wine
4  drink   10.5    soda
5  drink   12.0    soda
```

solution working well id multiple missing values per groups:

```
print (df)
    type  price product
0   food   19.0   apple
1   food   12.0     egg
2   food   21.0     NaN
3   food   19.0   apple
4   food   12.0     egg
5   food   13.0     NaN
6  drink   21.0    wine
7  drink   10.5    soda
8  drink   12.0     NaN
```

---

```
def f(x):
    
    m = x['product'].notna()
    a = x['price'].to_numpy()
    b = x['product'].to_numpy()
    
    arr = np.abs(a[m] - a[~m][:, None])

    out = b[m][np.argmin(arr, axis=1)]
    
    x.loc[~m, 'product'] = out
    return x


df = df.groupby('type').apply(f)
print (df)
    type  price product
0   food   19.0   apple
1   food   12.0     egg
2   food   21.0   apple
3   food   19.0   apple
4   food   12.0     egg
5   food   13.0     egg
6  drink   21.0    wine
7  drink   10.5    soda
8  drink   12.0    soda
```

Comment: thanks, this works, just wondering if there's a simpler solution

Comment: @ubertao - good question, I think mozway answer is simplier. If need custom function per groups this is best what I know ;)